# Basic ncsa authentication is not workling in squid

Tags: squid, http-basic-authentication

I'm using squid-3.3.8-12.el7_0.x86_64 on CentOS 7

I've configured squid for basic authentication, md5 password **works**, but if fails when I try to use either blowfish or sha password.

Below is the cache.log when it fails and squid.conf:

```
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(275) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 matched=0 async=0 finished=0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(299) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 simple mismatch
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(160) checkAccessList: 0x7f217e8baca8 checking 'http_access  allow squid_access'
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(336) matches: ACLList::matches: checking squid_access
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(319) checklistMatches: ACL::checklistMatches: checking 'squid_access'
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(281) aclCacheMatchFlush: aclCacheMatchFlush called for cache 0x7f217e9b8cc8
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(61) AuthenticateAcl: returning 2 sending credentials to helper.
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(321) checklistMatches: ACL::ChecklistMatches: result for 'squid_access' is -1
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(346) matches: squid_access needs async lookup
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Acl.cc(354) matches: squid_access result is false
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(275) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 matched=0 async=1 finished=0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(312) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 going async
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(131) asyncInProgress: ACLChecklist::asyncInProgress: 0x7f217e8baca8 async set to 1
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| AclProxyAuth.cc(144) checkForAsync: checking password via authenticator
2015/03/18 17:21:02.637 kid1| Checklist.cc(256) matchNodes: 0x7f217e8baca8 awaiting async operation
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(131) asyncInProgress: ACLChecklist::asyncInProgress: 0x7f217e8baca8 async set to 0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(160) checkAccessList: 0x7f217e8baca8 checking 'http_access  allow squid_access'
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(336) matches: ACLList::matches: checking squid_access
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(319) checklistMatches: ACL::checklistMatches: checking 'squid_access'
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(66) AuthenticateAcl: returning 3 sending authentication challenge.
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(146) markFinished: 0x7f217e8baca8 answer AUTH_REQUIRED for AuthenticateAcl exception
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(321) checklistMatches: ACL::ChecklistMatches: result for 'squid_access' is -1
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(343) matches: squid_access failed.
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Acl.cc(354) matches: squid_access result is false
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(275) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 matched=0 async=0 finished=1
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(294) matchNode: 0x7f217e8baca8 exception: AUTH_REQUIRED
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(88) matchNonBlocking: ACLChecklist::check: 0x7f217e8baca8 match found, calling back with AUTH_REQUIRED
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(182) checkCallback: ACLChecklist::checkCallback: 0x7f217e8baca8 answer=AUTH_REQUIRED
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Gadgets.cc(58) aclGetDenyInfoPage: got called for squid_access
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Gadgets.cc(77) aclGetDenyInfoPage: aclGetDenyInfoPage: no match
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| FilledChecklist.cc(77) ~ACLFilledChecklist: ACLFilledChecklist destroyed 0x7fffee83caa0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(334) ~ACLChecklist: ACLChecklist::~ACLChecklist: destroyed 0x7fffee83caa0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| FilledChecklist.cc(77) ~ACLFilledChecklist: ACLFilledChecklist destroyed 0x7fffee83caa0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(334) ~ACLChecklist: ACLChecklist::~ACLChecklist: destroyed 0x7fffee83caa0
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| FilledChecklist.cc(77) ~ACLFilledChecklist: ACLFilledChecklist destroyed 0x7f217e8baca8
2015/03/18 17:21:02.638 kid1| Checklist.cc(334) ~ACLChecklist: ACLChecklist::~ACLChecklist: destroyed 0x7f217e8baca8
2015/03/18 17:21:02.639 kid1| FilledChecklist.cc(77) ~ACLFilledChecklist: ACLFilledChecklist destroyed 0x7f217e8baca8
2015/03/18 17:21:02.639 kid1| Checklist.cc(334) ~ACLChecklist: ACLChecklist::~ACLChecklist: destroyed 0x7f217e8baca8
```

squid.conf:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl multimedia rep_mime_type -i "/etc/squid/acls/multimedia"`
acl unpriv src 192.168.32.0/24
http_reply_access deny multimedia
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
acl squid_access proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access  allow squid_access
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
debug_options ALL,1 33,2 28,9
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Show the relevant parts of squid.conf.

Comment: I've just added it.